# How to fix this Ursina python code error?

Tags: python, pycharm, ursina

I am coding this ursina code on pycharm but, it not working.

```
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()

window.color = color.rgb(255,0,255)
window.exit_button = False

app.run()
```

I don't know what is the problem in this code but this is the error that I received

```
 line 58, in __init__
    from screeninfo import get_monitors
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'screeninfo'
```

I tried using this [code](https://github.com/RedHenDev/ursina_tutorials/blob/main/python_minecraft_tut_2021/pyCraft_tut_22.py) that this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vX4l-qozib8) gave me but, there is still this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_______________________________________________________________", line 54, in __init__
    from AppKit import NSScreen
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AppKit'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mainguyen/PycharmProjects/beter_minecraft/main.py", line 54, in <module>
    from ursina import *
  File "_______________________________________________________________", line 9, in <module>
    from ursina.window import instance as window
  File "_______________________________________________________________", line 382, in <module>
    instance = Window()
  File_______________________________________________________________9/site-packages/ursina/window.py", line 58, in __init__
    from screeninfo import get_monitors
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'screeninfo'
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Make sure you have the module screeninfo installed. You can do this with the following command: `pip list`

Comment: Do the same for AppKit

Comment: There are no appkit.